# Как сделать ProgressBar невидимым

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

Есть список картинок, сделанный через RecyclerView. При нажатии на картинку, пока она передается в следующую активити должен отображаться ProgressBar. 
Когда происходит возврат в активити выбора изображений, то ProgressBar также остается видимым, хотя должен быть скрытым

```
public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_outline);
    progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progr);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageOnClick.onClick(getAdapterPosition());
            // по нажатию на картинку прогрессбар становится видимым
            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

**Адаптер**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ImageViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(listImages.get(position));
    holder.setImageOnC(new ImageOnC() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(int pos) {
            Common.PICTURE_SELECTED = listImages.get(pos);
            mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, Colorful.class));
        }
    });
}
```

**Насколько я понял, то нужно добавить в адаптер еще onBindViewHolder для того, чтобы скрыть прогрессбар**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder,  int position, List<Object> payload) {
    if (!payload.isEmpty()) {
        if (payload.get(0) != null) {
            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    } else {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payload);
    }
}
```

Если делать таким образом, то прогрессбар также остается видимым. Буду рад, если подскажете, что не так делаю.

Answer (score 0):

В первой активити добавьте этот код:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Если вы сохраните position нажатого item'а, то лучше вызвать

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но в таком случае прогрессбар становится невидимым 1 раз, при последующих нажатиях на другие изображения, прогрессбар становится активным